# Did family members of Osama Bin Laden get to leave America during the no-fly restrictions after 9/11?

Tags: terrorism, 9-11

Is there any proof that the family members of Osama Bin Laden got to leave America immediately following the 9/11 attacks, during the time when all air travel was banned?

Or is this just unverified, documentary film (e.g., [Fahrenheit 911](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_9/11)) stuff?

Comment: I could have sworn we had this one before, but I can't find it.... so, good question and I can't believe of all the 9-11 questions weve had this isnt one of them!

Comment: @Jamiec : We don't have that much different 9-11 questions. For the most part the kind of people who ask 9-11 questions don't focus on claims as specific as this when they ask questions on this website.

Comment: There are a number of articles and documents showing that the flights in question happened immediately after restrictions were lifted.  While the restrictions were lifted, it took a while for most commercial traffic to ramp back up, so many of those flights were still cancelled.  I will post an answer with links to FBI documents that were released, as well as the 9/11 Commission Report if no one else covers it when I'm not at work.

Comment: @Jamiec - I seem to vaguely recall a question on the topic as well, but also can't find it. Maybe we both read it on some other site?

Comment: If my name were "Bin Laden", I would have done anything in my power to leave the USA as quickly as possible after 9/11. And while many Americans would have been afraid of flying, I would have been more afraid to not fly.

Comment: I hear you, @gnasher729.  I have read that Osama's family members did not hold the same views as him; in particular, that they were not violent terrorists themselves, and that Osama was somewhat of a misfit / outcast of the family.  But if the American government made an exception for the Bin Laden family to fly out of the country (as claimed to be verified in the documentary, *Fahrenheit 911*), I do wonder how much more involved the government was, e.g., was there advanced information that the U.S. had of an imminent attack.

Comment: @User001: They are not "Osama's family members". The Bin Laden family is a huge family running a huge and highly successful construction business in Saudi Arabia and nearby countries. There are probably a hundred or so children, grand children, and grand grand children of the family founder, some involved in the business, many not much involved, and one of those over hundred was one guy named Osama. Osama bin Laden was just one distant member of the bin Laden family.

Answer (score 7):

Many of Osama bin Laden's family were protected by the FBI in the days following the attacks, but did not leave until the flight ban was lifted.

CBS News [gives a readable account of the events](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/bin-laden-family-evacuated/) in late September 2001:

> They left the country on a private charter plane when airports reopened three days after the attacks.

The allegations that they were permitted to leave before the flight bans were lifted was investigated by the [9/11 Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9/11_Commission).

The commission's [report](https://9-11commission.gov/report/911Report.pdf) has a section on this subject, titled "Flights of Saudi Nationals Leaving the United States", which asks the questions:

> 1. Did any flights of Saudi nationals take place before national airspace reopened on September 13, 2011?

They found no evidence for this - they could only find flights that happened after the national airspace had reopened.

> 2. Was there any political intervention to facilitate the departure of Saudi nationals?

They found no evidence that "anyone at the White House above the level of [Richard Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_A._Clarke#9.2F11_Commission) (a special assistant to the President) participated in a decision on the departure of Saudi nationals.

> 3. Did the FBI screen Saudi nationals thoroughly before their departure.

They concluded that the FBI conducted satisfactory screenings, and independently reviewed the Saudi nationals involved and confirmed they had no known links to terrorism.

Answer (score 0):

They were flown out, but not when air travel was banned.

Firstly, civilian air traffic was [allowed to resume](http://www.cnn.com/2001/TRAVEL/NEWS/09/13/faa.airports/) "at 11 a.m. EDT [eastern daylight time] Thursday [13 September 2001]", so there was only about a 48 hour period where flights were prohibited.

As explained in a 30 September 2001 New York Times [article](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/09/30/world/a-nation-challenged-the-family-fearing-harm-bin-laden-kin-fled-from-us.html):

> Both planes, one jumbo jet carrying 100 family members, and the other 40, were eventually allowed to leave when airports reopened and passports were checked

...

> The young members of the bin Laden clan were driven or flown under F.B.I. supervision to a secret assembly point in Texas and then to Washington from where they left the country on a private charter plane when airports reopened three days after the attacks.